# What does "didn't pace himself" means?

Tags: meaning

*For example*,

> **Raimund Preußen didn't pace himself at all**, and after a series of daring offensive runs he was too tired to help out in the defensive play.

Comment: [**pace oneself** do something at a slow and steady rate or speed in order to avoid overexerting oneself](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pace?region=us&q=pace+oneself#pace__10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Callithumpian answered you correctly. "Slow and steady" is of course variable, depending on the individual. There are many ways to use the idiom:

He **didn't pace himself**, so he ran out of energy and wasn't able to complete the marathon.

I have a lot of work to accomplish today, but I'm going to **pace myself** and take a 10 minute break at the end of every hour.

She has to swim 100 laps. If she **doesn't pace herself** there is no way she'll be able to complete them.

The bicycle race is 125 miles long. Sharon, stay with the lead if you can, **but pace yourself** so as not to burn out. Mike, try to keep within 25 cyclists of the lead and **pace yourself** so you'll have enough energy to sprint the last 10 miles. I'll hang back toward the middle and **pace myself** with the bulk of the racers so I'll have enough energy to sprint the last 35 miles of the race. With a little luck, our team will win.